# How to create a new column with if condition

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

This seems simple but I could not perform. Its different than sound similar question ask [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339995/conditionally-creating-a-new-column)
I want to create new columns say `df$col1`, `df$col2`, `df$col3` on dataframe df using if condition in the column already exists ie `df$con` and `df$val`.

1. I would like to write the value of column "val" in `df$col1` if `df$con > 3`
2. I would like to write the value of col `df$val` in `df$col2` if `df$con<2`
3. and I would like to write the 30% of `df$val` in `df$col3` if `df$con` is between 1 and 3.

How should I do it ? Below is my dataframe df with two columns "con" for condition and "val" for value use.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(con = c(-33.09524956, -36.120924, -28.7020053, 
-26.06385399, -18.45731163, -14.51817928, -20.1005132, -23.62346403, 
-24.90464018, -23.51471516), val = c(0.016808197, 1.821442227, 
 4.078385886, 3.763593573, 2.617612605, 2.691796601, 1.060565469, 
 0.416400183, 0.348732675, 1.185505136)), .Names = c("con", "val"
 ), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what defines the values for the columns in rows where the condition isn't true? e.g. what is the value of `col1` if `con` is <=3?  NA?

Comment: So you have two columns of all NA values in your example?

Comment: @Citrus Consider providing an example that reflect atleast some of the conditions rather than one doesn't meet any of the condition.

Comment: @RichardScriven, this is only sample data. so yes there will be only NA in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This might do it.  First we write a function to change FALSE values to NA

```
foo <- function(x) {
    is.na(x) <- x == FALSE
    return(x)
}
```

Then apply it over the list of logical vectors and take the matching `val` column values

```
df[paste0("col", 1:3)] <- with(df, {
    x <- list(con > 3, con < 2, con < 3 & con > 1)
    lapply(x, function(y) val[foo(y)])
})
```

resulting in

```
df
         con       val col1      col2 col3
1  -33.09525 0.0168082   NA 0.0168082   NA
2  -36.12092 1.8214422   NA 1.8214422   NA
3  -28.70201 4.0783859   NA 4.0783859   NA
4  -26.06385 3.7635936   NA 3.7635936   NA
5  -18.45731 2.6176126   NA 2.6176126   NA
6  -14.51818 2.6917966   NA 2.6917966   NA
7  -20.10051 1.0605655   NA 1.0605655   NA
8  -23.62346 0.4164002   NA 0.4164002   NA
9  -24.90464 0.3487327   NA 0.3487327   NA
10 -23.51472 1.1855051   NA 1.1855051   NA
```

Comment: Not sure how foo works (I'm relatively new to R) but answer is great (upvote).

Comment: @Marichyasana - it takes in a logical vector, and any elements that are `FALSE` get changed to `NA`

Answer (score 0):

Could go the tidyverse way. The pipes `%>%` just send the output of each operation to the next function. `mutate` allows you to make a new column in your data frame, but you have to remember to store it at the top. It's stored as `output`. The `ifelse` allows you to conditionally assign values to your new column, for example the column `col1`. The second argument in `ifelse` is the output for a true condition, and the third argument is when `ifelse` is false. Hope this helps some too!

Go tidyverse!

```
 library(tidyverse)

 output <- df %>%
   mutate(col1=ifelse(con>3, val, NA)) %>%
   mutate(col2=ifelse(con<2, val, NA)) %>%
   mutate(col3=ifelse(con<=3 & con>=1, 0.3*val, NA))
```

Here's a `df` that actually meets some of the conditions:

```
structure(list(con = c(-33.09524956, 2.5, -28.7020053, 2, -18.45731163, 
2, -20.1005132, 6, -24.90464018, -23.51471516), val = c(0.016808197, 
1.821442227, 4.078385886, 3.763593573, 2.617612605, 2.691796601, 
1.060565469, 0.416400183, 0.348732675, 1.185505136)), .Names = c("con", 
"val"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's the `output` after running the code:

```
         con       val      col1      col2      col3
1  -33.09525 0.0168082        NA 0.0168082        NA
2    2.50000 1.8214422        NA        NA 0.5464327
3  -28.70201 4.0783859        NA 4.0783859        NA
4    2.00000 3.7635936        NA        NA 1.1290781
5  -18.45731 2.6176126        NA 2.6176126        NA
6    2.00000 2.6917966        NA        NA 0.8075390
7  -20.10051 1.0605655        NA 1.0605655        NA
8    6.00000 0.4164002 0.4164002        NA        NA
9  -24.90464 0.3487327        NA 0.3487327        NA
10 -23.51472 1.1855051        NA 1.1855051        NA
```